# How to draw this object with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glut

I am trying to draw something like this in OpenGL 2.1 using GLU and GLUT primitives such as gluCylinder, glutSolidCylinder, etc.

[image: Cylinder with hole from Blender]

Basically it's a solid cylinder with a hole in the middle. So far I was unable to achieved it.
I also tried to import wavefront obj from Blender to my program in C++ but what I got was this.
[image: Something that is not cylinder from Blender]

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for(int i = 0; i < wheel->faces.size(); i++) {

        int nx = atoi(wheel->faces.at(i).at(0).substr(wheel->faces.at(i).at(0).find_last_of('/') + 1).c_str()) - 1;
        int ny = atoi(wheel->faces.at(i).at(1).substr(wheel->faces.at(i).at(1).find_last_of('/') + 1).c_str()) - 1;
        int nz = atoi(wheel->faces.at(i).at(2).substr(wheel->faces.at(i).at(2).find_last_of('/') + 1).c_str()) - 1;

        int vx = atoi(wheel->faces.at(i).at(0).substr(0, wheel->faces.at(i).at(0).find_first_of('/')).c_str()) - 1;
        int vy = atoi(wheel->faces.at(i).at(1).substr(0, wheel->faces.at(i).at(1).find_first_of('/')).c_str()) - 1;
        int vz = atoi(wheel->faces.at(i).at(2).substr(0, wheel->faces.at(i).at(2).find_first_of('/')).c_str()) - 1;

        glNormal3f(wheel->normals.at(nx).x, wheel->normals.at(ny).y, wheel->normals.at(nz).z);
        glVertex3f(wheel->vertices.at(vx).x, wheel->vertices.at(vy).y, wheel->vertices.at(vz).z);

    }
glEnd();
```

The parsing should be correct, I double checked it line by line. I guess it's the wrong way I tried to draw it.

However I don't want to use obj since my way of drawing makes animation slow (I am fairly new to OpenGL). And I don't want to use OpenGL 3+ either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you value your own sanity, get rid of `atoi` within drawing loop. Conversion should be done once at the loading stage, not on each draw.

Comment: Ofcourse. It's just for test.

Comment: @keltar I'd even start with `[]` instead of `at()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're drawing a single point with one face, however a face (a triangle) here is supposed to have three points.

Your may try this code:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
for(int i = 0; i < wheel->faces.size(); i++) {

    int v0 = atoi(wheel->faces.at(i).at(0).substr(0, wheel->faces.at(i).at(0).find_first_of('/')).c_str()) - 1;
    int v1 = atoi(wheel->faces.at(i).at(1).substr(0, wheel->faces.at(i).at(1).find_first_of('/')).c_str()) - 1;
    int v2 = atoi(wheel->faces.at(i).at(2).substr(0, wheel->faces.at(i).at(2).find_first_of('/')).c_str()) - 1;

    glVertex3f(wheel->vertices.at(v0).x, wheel->vertices.at(v0).y, wheel->vertices.at(v0).z);
    glVertex3f(wheel->vertices.at(v1).x, wheel->vertices.at(v1).y, wheel->vertices.at(v1).z);
    glVertex3f(wheel->vertices.at(v2).x, wheel->vertices.at(v2).y, wheel->vertices.at(v2).z);

}
glEnd();
```

I removed the normal part since I don't think you would need it for now. You may add it later.

**EDTIED:**
This seems better:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
for(int i = 0; i < wheel->faces.size(); i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        int v_id = atoi(wheel->faces.at(i).at(j).substr(0, wheel->faces.at(i).at(j).find_first_of('/')).c_str()) - 1;
        glVertex3f(wheel->vertices.at(v_id).x, wheel->vertices.at(v_id).y, wheel->vertices.at(v_id).z);
    }
glEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

Found for my self [this](https://github.com/syoyo/tinyobjloader) small lib for opening obj files.

Drawing loaded mesh with next code:

```
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for (size_t f = 0; f < shapes[0].mesh.indices.size(); f++) {
        glVertex3f(shapes[0].mesh.positions[3*f+0],
                   shapes[0].mesh.positions[3*f+1],
                   shapes[0].mesh.positions[3*f+2]);

    }
    glEnd();
```

Load mesh:

```
std::vector<tinyobj::shape_t> shapes;
int loadMesh(const char *file) {
    const char* basepath = NULL;
    std::string err = tinyobj::LoadObj(shapes, file, basepath);
    if (!err.empty()) {
        std::cerr << err << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "# of shapes : " << shapes.size() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```